# How can I transfer search container data in actionURL in Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I'm new to Liferay framework, started with this example portlet app in which users can add some strings to search container, maybe comments or whatever:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-your-first-liferay-application

What I'm currently trying to do is to add a possibility to delete selected entries from search container. I added one more column with checkbox:
[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXbKy.png). 
But I do not know how to transfer that column to my java controller class. This is how my jsp looks right now:

```
<jsp:useBean id="entries" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request"/> 

    <liferay-ui:search-container>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= entries %>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Entry"
        modelVar="entry"
    >

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>   
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBoxIds" name="myCheckBoxes" width="10"/>   
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="message" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="name" name="name" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>

  <portlet:actionURL name="deleteEntry" var="deleteEntryURL">   
    <portlet:param name="checkBoxes" value="WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO TRANSFER myCheckBoxes"></portlet:param>   
    </portlet:actionURL>

<aui:button-row cssClass="guestbook-buttons">
    <aui:button onClick="<%= addEntryURL.toString() %>" value="Add Entry"></aui:button>
    <aui:button onClick="<%= deleteEntryURL %>" value="Delete Entry"></aui:button>
</aui:button-row>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add checkbox explicitly but You can provide [rowChecker](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/RowChecker.html) attribute to lfieray's search-container tag.

Below javascript code will give you list of key value of checked rows, which you can then pass it to controller by setting it into hidden field.

`var checkBoxValue = Liferay.Util.listCheckedExcept(document.<portlet:namespace />fm, "<portlet:namespace />allRowIds");`